# Does this series $\cosh 1 + (\cosh 1-1)x^2+(\cosh1-1-\frac{1}{2!})x^4+(\cosh1-1-\frac{1}{2!}-\frac{1}{4!})x^6+\cdots$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, hyperbolic-functions

Can somebody help me with this?

$\cosh 1 + (\cosh 1-1)x^2+(\cosh1-1-\frac{1}{2!})x^4+(\cosh1-1-\frac{1}{2!}-\frac{1}{4!})x^6+\cdots$

Comment: It does. With summation by parts, you should even be able to find the sum.

Comment: What have you tried? This is a power series, and its radius of convergence is surely at most $1$, because the terms are bounded.

Comment: Kanak: Yes to the title question.  For the second question, I answer with a question: Why should we put effort into doing ***your*** homework, when you've shown no effort/thoughts on **your homework**?

Comment: @Kanak Dhorte don't just post problems also write down what you have tried

Answer (score 2):

For $|x|<1$ we can write

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\cosh(1)- \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{(2k-2)!}\right)x^{2n}&=\cosh(1)\frac{x^2}{1-x^2}-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k-2)!}\sum_{n=k}^\infty x^{2n}\\\\
&=\cosh(1)\frac{x^2}{1-x^2}-\frac{1}{1-x^2}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^{2k}}{(2k-2)!}\\\\
&=\cosh(1)\frac{x^2}{1-x^2}-\frac{x^2}{1-x^2}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^{2k-2}}{(2k-2)!}\\\\
&=\frac{x^2(\cosh(1)-\cosh(x))}{1-x^2}
\end{align}$$

---

More generally, we have

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^N\left(\cosh(1)- \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{(2k-2)!}\right)x^{2n}&=\cosh(1)\frac{x^2(1-x^{2N})}{1-x^2}-\sum_{k=1}^N \frac{1}{(2k-2)!}\sum_{n=k}^N x^{2n}\\\\
&=\cosh(1)\frac{x^2(1-x^{2N})}{1-x^2}-\frac{x^2}{1-x^2}\sum_{k=1}^N \frac{x^{2k-2}-x^{2N}}{(2k-2)!}\\\\
&=\frac{x^2}{1-x^2}\left(\cosh(1)-\sum_{k=1}^N\frac{x^{2k-2}}{(2k-2)!}\right)\\\\&+\frac{x^{2N+2}}{1-x^2}\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k-2)!}-\cosh(1)\right)\\\\
&=\frac{x^2}{1-x^2}\left(\cosh(1)-\sum_{k=1}^N\frac{x^{2k-2}}{(2k-2)!}\right)\\\\&-\frac{x^{2N+2}}{1-x^2}\left(\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k-2)!}\right)
\end{align}$$

Taking the limit as $N\to \infty$, we find that

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\cosh(1)- \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{(2k-2)!}\right)x^{2n}=\frac{x^2(\cosh(1)-\cosh(x))}{1-x^2}$$

for $|x|\ne 1$.

Comment: Actually, the derivation is valid for every $|x|\neq 1$, and the result (in the sense of a limit) even for $|x|=1$.

Comment: Well, the derivation is not literally valid. But if you multiply the series with $1-x^2$ and write $x^{2k}(1-x^2)=x^{2k}-x^{2k+2}$, you can use partial summation with the same result.

Comment: @ProfessorVector I've edited to add a general development.